# SUMIFS less than criteria in a table

Tags: excel

I have a simple table in a workbook to track monthly spend per *item*. What I'd like to do is work out the cumulative spend per item - I know I can do that using `SUMIFS()` but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Here's a screenshot of the workbook currently:
[image]

The formula for CumulativeSpend is

`=SUMIFS([Spend],[Item],[@Item], [YearMonth], [@YearMonth])`

however all that does is provide the same number as `[@Spend]`. What I need to do is sum up everything from `[@Spend]` where `[YearMonth]` is less than or equal to `[@YearMonth] but I can't figure out the syntax. I have tried all of the following:

`=SUMIFS([Spend],[Item],[@Item], [YearMonth], <=[@YearMonth])`
`=SUMIFS([Spend],[Item],[@Item], [YearMonth], "<="[@YearMonth])`

all of which are invalid formulae. I've also tried this:

`=SUMIFS([Spend],[Item],[@Item], [YearMonth], "<=[@YearMonth]")`

which is a valid formula but (unsurprisingly) it doesn't give the right answer.

A read-only copy of the workbook I've used here can be accessed at: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjcmU60daA9VquZIhFGJlUyysNmFCw

Can anyone give me the formula to calculate the CumulativeSpend per item per month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, immediately after posting this I figured it out!

`=SUMIFS([Spend],[Item],[@Item], [YearMonth], "<="&[@YearMonth])`

Answer (score 2):

You need to concatenate the string with `&`:

```
=SUMIFS([Spend],[Item],[@Item], [YearMonth], "<=" & [@YearMonth])
```

Comment: thanks, I think we posted at exactly the same time :)  Apparently I have to wait 13 minutes to accept your answer!